# How do I get the frame of visible content from SKCropNode?

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, sknode, skcropnode

It appears that, in SpriteKit, when I use a mask in a SKCropNode to hide some content, it fails to change the frame calculated by `calculateAccumulatedFrame`. I'm wondering if there's any way to calculate the visible frame.

A quick example:

```
import SpriteKit

let par = SKCropNode()

let bigShape = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
bigShape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
bigShape.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
par.addChild(bigShape)

let smallShape = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
smallShape.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()
smallShape.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
par.maskNode = smallShape

par.calculateAccumulatedFrame() // returns (x=0, y=0, width=100, height=100)
```

I expected `par.calculateAccumulatedFrame()` to return `(x=0, y=0, width=20, height=20)` based on the crop node mask.

I thought maybe I could code the function myself as an extension that basically reimplements `calculateAccumulatedFrame` with support for checking for SKCropNodes and their masks, but it occurred to me that I would need to consider the alpha of that mask to determine if there's actual content that grows the frame. Sounds difficult.

Is there an easy way to calculate this?

Comment: did you try using the frame property?

Comment: Pretty easy to test in a playground. Adding ```par.frame``` at the end returns ```(x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0)```. Doesn't help.

Comment: Use the frame of your mask node then aka smallNode

Comment: That completely defeats the point of my question though. I want to know, once a mask is applied, what rect contains all visible content. If the mask has transparency in different parts, the visible content rect may be smaller than the mask's rect.

Comment: no, the maskNode  is a node,  node's frame is always the smallest visible area, so if you do node.maskNode.frame, you will get the smallest visible portion of your masked area

Comment: if you are saying you have content that only stays inside the mask, then why bother using the mask,  waste of processing

Comment: For instance, masks can be sprite nodes, and pixels within those sprites may be transparent. This causes the crop node to hide the content in that pixel. If I have a non-standard shaped sprite for my mask or if I'm doing transformations on the mask, its frame isn't good enough to determine visible content of the crop node.

Comment: if sprites have transparent pixels, those transparent pixels do not get counted in its frame,  your frame is the first visible pixel to the left to the last visible pixel on the right,  if your sprite is smaller than the mask, then take the frame of the sprite, if your sprite is larger than the mask, than take the frame of the mask.  If you have some weird hybrid, then you will need to figure something else out, because the mask only affects what is rendered,  the idea is to still keep the content inside because at any time you could remove the mask

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize that the frame already accounted for invisible/visible pixels. Thanks.